# Facebook Graph API Post to Page returns duplicate ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I use the Facebook Graph API to post *to* a wall *as* that wall (using the **page access token** generated from a user with the appropriate permissions), the request always returns the same ID (so it successfully posts, but I'm not getting a **unique** ID--it's the same every time). As such, I can't get the actual post ID, so I can't delete that post. Has anyone else had this issue? Is there any way to get the actual ID? I've tried various libs and  methods, and this seems universal, so I don't think it's any sort of wrapper issue, but rather an issue with the Graph API itself.

Thanks!

UPDATE: It turns out this was an issue with the Ruby gem I was using--so it was in fact a wrapper issue.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're doing please? Are you posting via the graph API to a page wall using a page access token from an admin of that page? Posting to a user's wall with their own access token? Something else? You should be receiving a post ID back which can be queried at graph.facebook.com/<post ID here>

Comment: the ID should be unquie.  are u sure that u have catch an error / exception in calling fb api?

Comment: I've updated the question a bit to be more specific. To be clear: the post is successful. The response is just returning the same ID every time.

Comment: @ideaoforder you should write the answer to this question as an answer and accept it, so future users might be helped. :)

Comment: You should post your update as an answer. Also, it might be useful for future visitors if you could add more detail about which gem this was and how you solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To further clarify--I was using my own forked version of the Koala ruby gem (I added an option to send the request params as data, rather than form-encoded) and borked what was being returned. So this was entirely on me. Users of the Koala gem shouldn't have this issue.